# American native speaker and perfect tenses

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, past-tense, present-perfect-vs-simple-past, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

Yesterday I sent my friend a useful gift in online game. Today I can see he has not accepted it yet. Which sentence is grammatically correct *and* most natural in American English?

> 1. "You didn't use the Gift I gave you!"
> 2. "You didn't use the Gift I had given you!"
> 3. "You haven't used the Gift I gave you!"
> 4. "You haven't used the Gift I had given you!"

Somehow option 1 seems most natural, and yet is the least consistent with what I remember from English classes. Option 4 should be grammatically correct, but 2 perfect tenses in one sentence seem a bit odd.

Comment: 1 and 3 sounds ok to me - and 4 should likely be _You didn't use the gift I have given you_

Comment: Related: [When will “Present Perfect vs. Past Tense” cases be affected by culture?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3309/when-will-present-perfect-vs-past-tense-cases-be-affected-by-culture) and the questions linked from there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You didn't use the gift I gave you.

could imply that you thought the other party was supposed to use the gift at a specific point of time (or when a certain event occurred), and they have lost the opportunity.

> You haven't used the gift I gave you.

implies that *so far* the other party has not used the gift, but there's a chance they still will.