# I only watched or I have only watched

Tags: tenses, past-tense, perfect-aspect

If someone ask me
"Do you like Indian movie?"

Which tenses would fit the answer to the question ?

1. "yes I do. But I watched only some of them"
2. "yes I do. But I have wathed only some of them"
3. "yes I do. But I had watched only some of them"

thanks in advance

budi

Comment: Only style advice, so I'll keep it to a comment - In my opinion, the second sentence is the most correct of the three, but "only" should precede "watched."  "I have only watched some of them."

Comment: Incidentally, if someone were to ask you if you like Indian movies, it is unlikely that she would think you had watched "all" of them.  As such, a simple "Yes I do" would suffice.  Saying you have only watched some of them might come off as a catty response.  If you were to say "Yes I do, but I have only watched a few of them" I would perceive the response as more polite.  Just my opinion, for what it's worth.

Comment: thank you Lumberjack for the correction. I should say "a few of them" instead of "some of them". And that's (a few) exactly what I meant.

Comment: If someone asked me "Do you like Indian movie?", I might ask him which Indian movie *(singular)* he is talking about.

Comment: This question has been asked hundreds of times before. Start by looking at the following three questions: [One](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/) provides a general overview of how the different tenses in English correspond to one another; [two](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/), and the related questions linked from there, address your question more directly; [three](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3309/) addresses an important difference between British and American English.

Comment: We also have an [entire tag](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pp-vs-sp?sort=votes&pagesize=50) dedicated to choosing between Present Perfect and Simple Past.

Answer (score 0):

If someone asks you "Do you like Indian movie?", I think you should answer "**Yes I do. But I HAVE watchED only some of them.**" Indeed, watching them has had some consequences on your present life, since you're still remembering them. It is not a simply action that you did in your past, such as "Yesterday, I ate a sandwich. Then..". (Ok, this example is quite bad but its was the only one that I thought about..).
Nonetheless, I am not TOTALLY sure, cause I'm French...but let's say I'm quite sure of it (I said QUITE..!!)
Does this answer suit you?

Buona giornata !

Comment: Oh, I've just re-read my answer, and It would be "I have ONLY watched some of them", and not what I said in my commentary!

Comment: merci beaucoup Mr. Tiersen :)

Comment: I would suggest that your original version "I have watched ONLY some of them" is more correct: the "only" is qualifying "some", not "watched". "Only watched some of them" *could* mean "I've listened to all of them but not watched all of them."