# When to use "have"/"has" and when not to use "have"/"has" in a sentence

Tags: present-perfect-vs-simple-past

1. I heard about it.
   I have heard about it.
2. I knew him.
   I have known him.
3. He has played really well.
   He played really well.

Comment: Really, this comes down to the basics of the past, perfect and pluperfect tenses in English, which would be a general reference (any book or resource on English grammar will cover this). I'd recommend [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/21847/15770) as being a nice summary.

Comment: Please search the site before asking. Here are a couple links for your convenience. [This one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21846/) provides a general overview of how the different tenses in English correspond to one another. [This one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1357/), and the questions linked from there, addresses the choice between Present Perfect and Simple Past more directly. [This one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3309/) addresses an important difference between BrE and AmE. For more information still, we have a dedicated tag, which I have added to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The examples given are instances of [present perfect tense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect) contrasted with past tense.  The present perfect generally emphasizes the present importance of past events, as opposed to a simple past tense, which in English may denote a completed action.  Without more context it's hard to impute it here, but for the sake of argument, the simple past tense ("I knew him") might, by deemphasizing a present relevance, mean that the acquaintanceship ended or diminished at some point.

The third example ("He has played really well") seems to summarize the past (leading to a present state of affairs), while a simple past tense ("He played really well") might point to a specific (completed) past event.