# "How long have you stayed there?" vs "How long did you stay there?"

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense, present-perfect-vs-simple-past, perfect-aspect

I have a doubt about the difference between those two questions.

Could you guys give me an appropriate examples and explanation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please search the site before asking. Here are a couple links for your convenience. [This one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21846/) provides a general overview of how the different tenses in English correspond to one another. [This one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1357/), and the questions linked from there, addresses the choice between Present Perfect and Simple Past more directly. [This one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3309/) addresses an important difference between BrE and AmE. For more information still, we have a dedicated tag, which I have added to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
“How long have you stayed there?”
```

It is in the present perfect tense .
means that he stayed there and he is still there

```
“How long did you stay there?”
```

It is in the past simple tense . means that he stayed there and he isn't there now

Generally , the present perfect tense means that the Subject did "verb" and he is still doing it . or , he did something and have effect for now . 
and the past simple tense means that he did something , finish it and have no effect for now .

Comment: You have an interesting way of using the period. What language is that?

Comment: English I guess !

Comment: Thank you for answering.. But now I've got more confused...ㅠㅠ