# I hope you enjoyed/have enjoyed staying in Italy

Tags: present-perfect, simple-past

A friend has written me a message in which she tells me that she is leaving tomorrow from Italy. I want to say that I hope that she had/ has had a great time here in Italy. What is the right way to say it? "I hope you enjoyed staying in Italy" or "I hope you have enjoyed etc.." Thanks.

Comment: This has been covered [many times before](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3309). [This question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21846/) provides a general overview of how the different tenses in English correspond to one another. [This one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1357/), and the related questions linked from there, addresses the choice between Present Perfect and Simple Past more directly. [This one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3309/) addresses an important difference between British and American English. We have dedicated tags, too. Have a look around.

Answer (score 0):

According to Raymond Murphy's English grammar in use, you can use the present perfect for new or recent happenings. l'd say both are correct,but l would stick to the present perfect sentence since you're supposed to be writing a message.l think the the present perfect is always the best choice when it comes to writing. l hope l have helped.