# I copied or I have copied?

Tags: tenses, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

As I speak, I noticed that I use the word "have" a lot! Also, I was wondering whether this over-usage is right. For instance,

> I have copied the file to your computer

where I could've used

> I copied the file to your computer

instead! Am I right or do they differ subtly?

Comment: About the point that you use "have" in your sentences, a better way would be to use a contraction, meaning "I've" instead of "I have".

Comment: Please search the site before asking. Here are a couple links for your convenience. [This one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21846/) provides a general overview of how the different tenses in English correspond to one another. [This one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1357/), and the questions linked from there, addresses the choice between Present Perfect and Simple Past more directly. [This one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3309/) addresses an important difference between BrE and AmE. For more information still, we have a dedicated tag, which I have added to your question.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I usually trust the search engine to give me the duplicate question just as I type them after clicking the 'Ask Question' button on the home page.